# Is it possible to connect alexa output to amazon SQS

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have created a alexa smart home function and want to run it asynchronously so plan to use amazon sqs (Simple que service) functionality. I connected amazon sqs trigger output to lambda function and successfully able to send message from sqs to lambda. Now need to connect the alexa to sqs input. When i try to use sqs arn in alexa developer console it does not support it. Is there any way to solve this or will alexa support only lambda function for invocation.

The alexa skill is for smart home service to control switches (Turn on/off), so when try to control the multiple switches because of synchronous nature execution of lambda it turns on switches one after the other. I need to control them at single shot so need asynchronous execution for lambda where requests need to execute without waiting for the response.

Thanks in advance for answers.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work as SQS works asynchronus and just reply that message was put there. But Alexa needs a valid JSON response with speech tag and so on immediately and SQS is not able to fulfill this.
What you could do:
Alexa -> Lambda (new) -> SQS - Lambda
In your new created lambda you could give a valid reply to Alexa and put a message in SQS.

Comment: Is this the only way to make alexa work asynchrously, earlier it worked properly without delay turn on/off worked recently only it changed executing one by one.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda can work asynchronously. You can have a bunch of back-end processes all working as they need to, triggering various Lambdas as needed.

But the exchange with Alexa opens a session to your backend, sends its request, and the full response is expected to end that session. That response may have directives to download other content to incorporate into the response, like a sound file or lazy loading a list in APL. But it is expecting a full response.

If you go through the basic Cake Time tutorial for building Alexa skills, they actually use async-await for some APIs because that response has to be complete before it's sent.

There are some async APIs like reminders and proactive events, but they're NOT conversational. They're unique one-way messages.

The real questions are why do you feel you need to do it this way and what are you optimizing for by queuing?

Comment: The alexa skill is for smart home service to control switches (Turn on/off), so when try to control the multiple switches because of synchronous execution of lambda it turns on switches one after the other. I need to control them at single shot so need asynchronous execution for lambda